# libnet device (Network interface) command line argument

Tags: windows, networking, driver, libnet

I just git libnet project from https://github.com/sam-github/libnet/tree/master/libnet and i have been looking over the example source provided with it.the example obtain a cmd arg called "device" to initialize libnet. I figured out "eth0" is the proper value on Linux OS but I'm using windows 7 and my question is what can i use as value for device on windows.

```
l = libnet_init(
    LIBNET_RAW4,                  /* injection type */
    device,                       /* network interface */
    errbuf);                      /* errbuf */
```

I tried a lots of values like adaptor name, device index, etc... but every time i got this error:

```
libnet_init() failed: libnet_link_win32.c(): unable to open the driver, error Code : 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by the same problem.
It can be solve like this.

in lib wpcap

there is a function named `pcap_findalldevs();`

use it like this and you will succuss

```
int Value = pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs,errbuf);
if( Value == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
char *device = NULL;
device = alldevs->name; //get the first Card name

    libnet_t *l

l = libnet_init(
    LIBNET_LINK_ADV,
    device,//use it here
    error_information);
```

may this help you. good luck!